# How to save a file into my system or connect it to PowerBI directly

Tags: python, powerbi

So I read a CSV file in my Jupyter Notebook on chrome (using pd.read_csv())

It consists of about 86,000 rows and about 5 columns. It's a mix of numerical and string data. I cleaned/manipulated it adding a column and deleting null values.

I now wish to connect this data in my PowerBI to visualize it.

Can I save it as a JSON file in my computer and then upload it in powerBI?

Is there a way to directly dump all the contents into a PowerBI report?

What are my options?

Comment: Is your file CSV or JSON? And Is the file/data present locally on your machine or in a website? It'd be easier to help if you could share some sample data and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy and paste  the content of your report in PowerBI webapp

[image: Copy the CSV content to power bi report]

Once your report is ready, Save it, you can access the Power BI report using jupyter notebook book by installing powerbiclient library

```
from powerbiclient.authentication import DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication
device_auth = DeviceCodeLoginAuthentication()
token_with_device_code = device_auth.get_access_token()

group_id='ca8b6b59-919d-4f7e-92a2-eab66a7dd536' #your groupid in workspace
report_id='5cb9a453-b3b0-4695-98c9-98ed8f7ad4ba' #your report id in workspace 
report=Report(group_id=group_id,report_id=report_id,auth=device_auth)
report
```

In case of difficulty  you can refer my post on [how to connect powerBI report in jupyter notebook](https://mymlspace.com/integrating-power-bi-with-jupyter-notebook/)